# htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with a link in a newsletter. The link point to a file (.wav) who is on the server but when I click on it on the newsletter I got an http 400 error, which means the file is missing. But it is on my server.

I've tried to make a redirection to another file (.zip) The redirection doesn't work but I can download the file.

My file is called like that:
trak(Extended_Intro+Outro).wav

and the zip is: track.zip

My htaccess looks like that:

```
AddType audio/x-wav .wav
AddType audio /wav .Wav
AddType application/octet-stream .wav

Redirect 301 /newsletter/music/track(Extended_Intro+Outro).wav
```

http://mysite/newsletter/music/track.zip

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Regards

Comment: http 400 is actually "bad request"

Comment: I think the formatting of your AddType is wrong: remove the excess spacing on the second line.

Comment: @U4ik_Haze: yes, that "audio /wav" is wrong. should be "audio/wav".

Answer (score 1):

i'm having a hard time trying to figure out what it is you're actually trying to do.

you want to redirect a request for a specific .wav file to a specific .zip file?  or the other way around?

in either case, why?  they're different types of files, not really interchangable.

As for the htaccess problem, do you have:

- AccessFileName defined in your apache config?

see: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

- AllowOverride configured for the directory concerned?

  You need FileInfo allowed for AddType and Redirect to work in a .htaccess file.

  Watch our for "AllowOverride None" in a higher level dir - that disables htaccess settings for the directory and all subdirectories (but will be overridden by more specific AllowOverride rules that are defined for subdirectories)

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've updated the htaccess without the space but it doesn't anything unfortunately. Regards

Comment: what's a space got to do with anything i wrote?